# Not able to debug from one web app to another web app

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am running two web application using IntelliJ. Both are running on `http port 8080` and for one I have changed `jmx port to 9099`. Issuse is when I try to call another app using httpget  `HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(http://localhost:8080/b-app);` from the a-app, http request never hitting `http://localhost:8080/b-app`. Do I need any specific configuration in intelliJ for it?

Thanks for the help

Comment: As long as you don't know what it is, you should leave the JMX port alone.

Comment: You can't run two instances of a server on the same port. Are you just deploying two apps to tomcat? Or do you get stack traces when you start the second app? And, what do you mean by 'debug'?

Comment: I don't understand how you run two web applications deploying on two different tomcats on the same machine and both tomcats listen to port `8080`. How do you do that?

Comment: @EngineerDollery I can deploy two app to tomcat without any issue. But I want to debug app running in debug mode using intelliJ and want to intercet the call that I am making from one web app to another

Comment: @Peter I am two different app on one tomcat. Sorry if I am not clear in my question above.